Función lambda para extraer usuarios de QuickSight y reescribirlos en csv y almacenarlos en un bucket s3 existente
Objetivo: Función lambda para extraer usuarios de QuickSight y reescribirlos en csv y almacenarlos en un bucket s3 existente
Proceso: Logre extraer todos los usuarios en QuickSight pero no puedo reestructurarlo en un scv y almacenarlo en un bucket s3 ya existente
Problema: Logro hacer la extracción de los usuarios, pero no logro transcribirlo en un csv con mejor formato y exportarlo a un bucket s3 ya existente
import boto3
import json
import csv 
from io import StringIO

  
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')  
quicksight_client = session.client('quicksight')  
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

csv_file_path = ''
bucket_name = '****'
file_path = '****'

account_id = '****'
namespace = 'default' 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = quicksight_client.list_users(
        AwsAccountId= account_id,
        Namespace=namespace
    )
    
    print("Respuesta completa:", json.dumps(response, indent=2))

    # Verificar si la clave 'UserSummaryList' está en la respuesta y obtén los usuarios
    user_list = response.get('UserSummaryList', [])

    if not user_list:
        print("No se encontraron usuarios en el namespace especificado.")
        return  # Salir de la función si no hay usuarios
    
    print("Lista de usuarios obtenida correctamente.")
        
 
    # Guarda los datos en un archivo CSV
    with open(csv_file_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        # Define los encabezados del CSV
        headers = ['Arn', 'UserName', 'Email', 'Role', 'Active']
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)  # Crea el escritor CSV
        writer.writerow(headers)  # Escribe los encabezados

        # Escribe los datos de los usuarios
        for user in user_list:
            row = [
                user.get('Arn', ''),
                user.get('UserName', ''),
                user.get('Email', ''),
                user.get('Role', ''),
                user.get('Active', '')
            ]
            writer.writerow(row)  # Escribe la fila en el CSV
    
    # Sube el archivo CSV a S3
    s3.upload_file(csv_file_path, bucket_name, file_path)
    print(f"Archivo CSV guardado en S3: s3://{bucket_name}/{file_path}")


Ya probé que si tenga una lista de usuario, que es lo que me recomiendan revisar primero, pero si no tuviera una lista de usuarios no podría visualizar a los usuarios 

